# Is there any way to remove or rename local URL to hide the address?

Tags: url, browser, hide, local

I have a html file and use it for my job. when I open this file with browser the URL shows the address of file location in address bar (in this case on my desktop)

`file:///C:/Users/Sina/Desktop/File.html`

I need some settings that local users cant change any thing to original file. when local users saw the address, they change or delete file.

Is there any way to hide, remove, rename or ... to not show the real address or location of the file? (on this PC or any PC when run)

some settings like just show the name of file

`File.html`

Comment: What do you want to acheve? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase I need some settings that local users cant change any thing to original file. when local users saw the address, they change or delete file.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible unless you are running it on a server. You can use the **.htaccess** file to define mod_rewrite rules if you are planning to move it to server. Please look into this tutorial [video tutorial](https://youtu.be/-6LyG9I-FPc) to do so.

Comment: Thank you. So I must running it on a server

Comment: Yes. If it is necessary you should try it.